# Converting mysql column with type of "datetime" to "time" using Rails migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime

A migration I've created appears to change a column type from `datetime` to `time`, however it's still storing things as a datetime.

My migration looked like this:

```
class ChangeEventStartTime < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :events, :start_time, :time
  end
end
```

I run the migration. Everything looks fine... and when I check the column's type:

```
irb(main):010:0> Event.columns_hash["start_time"].type
=> :datetime
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Check the status of the migration `rake db:migrate:status`. Is it showing `up` or `down`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you've run the migration.

Because, if the MySQL type is `DATETIME` of `TIMESTAMP`, Rails represents is `DateTime`. But for `DATE` and `TIME`, Rails represents it as-is: Date and Time. Only for the `DATETIME`/`TIMESTAMP` does Rails take an auto-decision for us. For the rest, it maintains as-is.